# Fetch only the department that has the highest number of employees

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my database.

```
 Table 1. employee
id
name
department_id



 Table 2. department
id
name
```

What will be the query to fetch all employees with their department?
So I have written this query

```
SELECT employee.name
     , department.name 
  FROM employee 
  JOIN department 
    ON employee.department_id = department.id
```

And this seems to be correct but I am not able to write a query if I want to fetch only the department that has the highest number of employees. How can I achieve this?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: you need to use nested query to do that. check this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

Comment: Do you need to select just the department that has the most employees, or also select all of that department's employees?

Comment: @MatBailie yes only department that has most employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee just ***one*** department...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  department
WHERE
  id = (SELECT department_id
          FROM employee
      GROUP BY department_id
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
         LIMIT 1
       )
```

Note, if two departments are tied with joint maximum employees, this will still only select One of them (arbitrarily chosen, potentially different each time).

To handle ties, you could do the following...

```
SELECT *
  FROM department
 WHERE id IN (SELECT department_id
                FROM employee
            GROUP BY department_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                   FROM employee
                               GROUP BY department_id
                               ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                                  LIMIT 1
                                )
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a real pain to handle in MySQL.  Here is one option:

```
SELECT d1.id, d1.name
FROM department d1
INNER JOIN employee e1
    ON d1.id = e1.department_id
GROUP BY d1.id, d1.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM department d2 INNER JOIN employee e2
                       ON d2.id = e2.department_id
                   GROUP BY d2.id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Note that if you were using a database with analytic function support, such as SQL Server, then the problem gets much easier:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM
(
    SELECT d.id, d.name, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) dr
    FROM department d
    INNER JOIN employee e
        ON d.id = e.department_id
    GROUP BY d.id, d.name
) t
WHERE t.dr = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved in multiple ways:

**Using sub query**

```
SELECT name FROM department
WHERE id IN
(SELECT department_id FROM employee HAVING COUNT(department_id)
IN
(SELECT MAX(COUNT(department_id)) FROM employee) GROUP BY department_id)
```

**Using Join**

```
SELECT name FROM employee e
INNER JOIN
department d ON e.department_id = d.id
HAVING COUNT(e.department_id)
IN
(SELECT MAX(COUNT(department_id)) from employee) group by department_id)
```

Comment: Little hint: You also indent and format application code do it also with SQL code makes it alot eazier to write and read then a long single line.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. Done!

Answer (score 0):

first check the column related two types have same name, same data type and the use subquery

```
SELECT name 
FROM department 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT department_id 
    FROM employees 
    HAVING COUNT(department_id) IN (
        SELECT MAX(COUNT(dept_id)) 
        FROM employees
    ) 
    GROUP BY department_id
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your query should work for the first question.

for the second, You can use this. The sub query would give you the dept Id for the most employees, which the outer query would give additional details for.

```
select * from department where department_id in
(select limit 1 Employee.department_id from Employee group by department_id 
order by count(Employee.name) desc)
```

Comment: This is MySQL, not SQL Server

Comment: This is a MySQL question, not SQL Server (to repeat the above comment).

Comment: I'm sorry , but which part of the query is not supported by MySQL? And I interpreted the question as "my query for SQL" and not MySQL query.

Comment: `TOP 1` vs `LIMIT 1`?